# Pattern for develping an extensible application with immutable deployment environment

Tags: django, docker, plugins, deployment

This is the problem at hand:

I'm developing a system that has as one of its core requirements extensibility: there should be the ability to develop plug-ins that extend the core functionalities. The application will provide some core API and developers will be able to write packages and extensions that add features.

One thing I'm having issues designing is the following: let's say a plug-in is represented as a folder with a certain structure; how should the plug-in be installed onto the main application?

Traditionally, many web apps used to be extensible by means of uploading a plug-in's code to a specific folder inside of the application, with some mechanism for the main application to discover new plug-ins.

The way I plan on deploying the application I'm developing is by means of containers: either by writing a Dockerfile for it, or by using Dokku. Both of those ways involve working with a repository and deploying to immutable environments: this makes the idea of adding code to a folder problematic because that code would be versioned and would change the repository, which is not what I want because adding a plug-in shouldn't be something that alters the codebase in my opinion.

For example, if somebody decides to fork the repository of my application, add a folder with the plug-in, and deploy it, it'll be problematic to stay in sync if the main codebase is updated.

For this reason, I'm trying to come up with a way to add plug-ins to an application without touching its code base and in a way that is compatible with immutable deploying such as when using docker.

Are there any known patterns for achieving this?
If it's relevant, the system I'm developing is made up of two separate applications: a Django REST backend and a Vue.js frontend, both deployed in two separate containers.

Comment: If you want a single deployable image that can reconfigure with different plugins, one way would be to have plugins be part of the _configuration_ of your application. So installing (and potentially removing/disabling) plugins is a matter of updating a configuration. The most flexible/extensible way to do this without reinventing the wheel would probably be to use Django reusable apps as Python packages. You can make your `settings.py` dynamically obtain values to insert into `INSTALLED_APPS`. In your container entrypoint, you can inspect the plugin list, install them, run migrations, etc.

Comment: A more container-native approach, that doesn't involve modifying containers or sharing files, could be to have a standard network protocol for your plugins and have some way for the plugins and main server to discover each other.  You might take some inspiration from the [Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol), nominally a way to write language plugins for Visual Studio Code but that plugs into many other IDEs as well.

Comment: @sytech I really like this idea. When it comes to the frontend part of plugins, how would you tackle the issue? I feel it's going to be more complex than with the backend, as the vue components are compiled into js and bundled.

Comment: @DavidMaze so if I understand correctly, you're saying fetch the plugin code from over the network, right? Interesting, could be done by having a plugin CDN; I can only imagine two issues. First of all, wouldn't it make performance worse, if part of the application logic is delegated to a piece of code over the net? Maybe I could fetch the plugins at startup time and not continuously look to discover them, making a local copy of the ones I find. Second thing is security: I imagine there'd be some caveats to having your app execute code downloaded from the net, even if from a secure source

Comment: Not necessarily; just run the plugin as a second container on the same Docker network.